# Where to use barrier pattern in java?

Tags: java, phaser

I've just read the javadoc about `Phaser` [there](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) and have a question about usage that class. The javadoc provides a sample, but what about real-life example? Where such a barrier implementation could be useful in practise?

Comment: Have you seen this article - http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/phaser/java-util-concurrent-phaser-example/ . ? It describes pretty well the adventages and used cases of Phaser.

Comment: The article hardly goes beyond what the javadoc exposes and the example is far from being real-world.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used `Phaser`, but I have used `CountDownLatch`. The referenced docs says:

> [`Phaser` is] similar in functionality to ... `CountDownLatch` but supporting more flexible usage.

`CountDownLatch` is useful anywhere where you fire off multiple threads to do some tasks, and in old-school you would have used `Thread.join()` to wait for them to finish.

---

For example:

**Old School:**

```
Thread t1 = new Thread("one");
Thread t2 = new Thread("two");

t1.start();
t2.start();    

t1.join();
t2.join();
System.out.println("Both threads have finished");
```

**Using `CountDownLatch`**

```
public class MyRunnable implement Runnable {
    private final CountDownLatch c;  // Set this in constructor

    public void run() {
        try {
            // Do Stuff ....
        } finally {
            c.countDown();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
CountDownLatch c = new CountDownLatch(2);

executorService.submit(new MyRunnable("one", c));
executorService.submit(new MyRunnable("two", c));

c.await();
System.out.println("Both threads have finished");
```

Comment: Your answer is off the topic. OP asked specifically about Phaser, not about CountDownLatch.

Comment: The OP asked about "the barrier pattern" and for real-life examples. `CountDownLatch` is indeed an implementation of that, and my example is cut down from real-life code.

Comment: Are you down on people providing help or something? YOU read the question again. The question asks for an example of the barrier pattern. There are no other answers. Maybe my answer doesn't meet your super-perfect exacting standards, but I do think it qualifies as "useful", which is the only criteria for up- or down-votes.

Comment: OP asked specifically about real-life example of Phaser barrier. So your answer is not useful at all. EOT from my side.